# GROUP BY clause to get comma-separated values in sqlite

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

My table structure is like this, using sqlite3

```
           CREATE TABLE enghindi (eng TEXT,hindi TEXT)
```

i have an table named **enghindi** in that there is two column named **hindi**, **eng**, i want to merge eng column's record and also combine hindi word by comma separated

look at the below table is looking like

[image]

i want to do look like this below

[image]

i want to do this with sqlite3 query

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(eng), hindi FROM enghindi GROUP BY hindi;
```

Comment: Thank you sooooooo much Sajuna Fermando :) you have saved my so much time

Comment: ya sure dost it says me you can accept answer after 15 min :(

Comment: Thats fine mate. No worries.

Comment: Hi Sajuna Fernando can you upvote my question and if you are free than  pls try to solve my next query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356996/join-on-two-different-tables-column-sqlite3