# join on two different table's column sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

hi have a two table one table contain column named

Table A
 _id, Eng, Hindi

other table contain

Table B
 _id, Eng, Hindi

**i want to join two table by matching word with Eng** if Eng word is not match it will be added into Table A which is from Table B otherwise Table A's value will be remain

for example

Now Table B

[image]

Table A

[image]

The Result would be on TABLE A is

[image]

Comment: Are you running MySQL on Android?

Comment: no using only Sqlite3

Comment: Do you need to actually insert/update (into) TableA or you just need to get the desired resultset from both tables? If it's former then how is `A_id` is maintained? Is it an `auto_increment`?

Comment: i just need to get the dsired resultset from both table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FULL JOIN` is a term to combine rows from multiple table. Does not apply to your needs.

You only need to insert into table `a` all entries in table `b` which are not in table `a`.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE a(Eng, Hindi) SELECT Eng, Hindi FROM b WHERE eng NOT IN (SELECT eng FROM a);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot also LS_dev

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get (`SELECT`) the desired output and `TableA` can contain records that are not present in `TableB` then you can emulate `FULL JOIN` to achieve your goal

```
SELECT e.eng, COALESCE(a.hindi, b.hindi) hindi
  FROM
(
  SELECT eng FROM TableB 
   UNION 
  SELECT eng FROM TableA
) e LEFT JOIN TableB b 
    ON e.eng = b.eng LEFT JOIN TableA a
    ON e.eng = a.eng
```

If on the other hand `TableA` **always** contains only a subset of `eng` values of `TableB` then you can just use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT b.eng, COALESCE(a.hindi, b.hindi) hindi
  FROM TableB b LEFT JOIN TableA a
    ON b.eng = a.eng
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/6f114/2)** demo

---

Now if you want to update the content of `TableA` and assuming that `A_id` is `AUTOINCREMENT`you can do

```
INSERT INTO TableA (eng, hindi)
SELECT b.eng, b.hindi
  FROM TableB b LEFT JOIN TableA a
    ON b.eng = a.eng
 WHERE a.eng IS NULL
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/86ae7/1)** demo

or

```
INSERT INTO TableA (eng, hindi)
SELECT b.eng, b.hindi
  FROM TableB b
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT * 
    FROM TableA
   WHERE eng = b.eng
);
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/f132e/1)** demo

Comment: It's not clear from OP's question whether `UPDATE` is actually needed.

Comment: peterm i am getting desired result but the data which is on table B is not inserted in table A (just on desired result)

Comment: @SiddhpuraAmit That was my question whether you actually want to update the content of `TableA` or you just need to select the desired resultset from both tables?

Comment: @SiddhpuraAmit See updated answer for a possible solution if you need to update the content of `TableA`