# Displaying Multiple values from a Junction table with Explode in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm working on school project. Where I have made a junction table for a **Teacher** and **Subjects**. The **Teacher** table contains the t_id and t_name and the **Subjects** table contains the sub_id and sub_name. Whereas in the junction name I have made foreign keys of t_id and sub_id. Now when I choose multiple subjects and then display it in the UI. It repeats the t_id 3 times if I select 3 subjects. I just want to show the t_id once with the 3 sub_id with comma that separates them in a table. [Click here to see the screenshot of the current table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoutJ.png).

This is the current code I have written:

```
<?php

    $que = "select teacher.t_name,teacher.qualification,teacher.gender,subject.sub_name from teacher join teach_sub_junction on teacher.t_id=teach_sub_junction.teacher_id join subject on subject.sub_id=teach_sub_junction.subject_id";
    $i = 1;

        if($row = mysql_query($que)){

            while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($row)){
                 $tname = $result['t_name'];
                 $qualification = $result['qualification'];
                 $gender = $result['gender'];
                 $sub_name = $result['sub_name'];
                 ?>

            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $i; $i++; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $tname; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $gender; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $qualification; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $sub_name; ?></td>
            </tr>
<?php       }
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can GROUP_CONCAT(subject.sub_id) and GROUP BY teacher.t_id to show the t_id once with the 3 sub_id with comma that separates them in a table.

Refer :  [GROUP BY clause to get comma-separated values in sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332722/group-by-clause-to-get-comma-separated-values-in-sqlite)